# Angularjs Multiple ng-Model filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form that I need to filter depending on what the user types in a text box, or by what they select in a dropdown list.  The textbox filter works great until I try to add in the dropdown list selection, then neither filter works.  Here is my Html:

```
 <div class="row">
            <table class="table" id="results">
                <thead style="background-color:#003A5D; color:white">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Company Name</td>
                        <td>City</td>
                        <td>State</td>
                        <td>Company Type</td>
                        <td>System ID</td>
                        <td>Releast Status</td>
                        <td>Training Tracker</td>
                        <td>SSQ Complete</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="contractor in contractors | filter: search ">
                        <td id="companyname">{{contractor.vchCompanyName}}</td>
                        <td id="city">{{contractor.vchOprCity}}</td>
                        <td id="state">{{contractor.vchOprStateID}}</td>
                        <td id="companytype">{{contractor.CompanyType}}</td>
                        <td id="companyid">{{contractor.CompanyID}}</td>
                        <td id="status">{{contractor.ReleaseStatus}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div ng-switch="contractor.TrainingTracker">
                                <div ng-switch-when="true">
                                    <span style="color:green" ng-bind-html="contractor.TrainingTracker | applyMarks | trustedhtml"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div ng-switch-when="false"><span style="color:red" ng-bind-html="contractor.TrainingTracker | applyMarks | trustedhtml"></span></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div ng-switch="contractor.SSQComplete">
                                <div ng-switch-when="true">
                                    <span style="color:green" ng-bind-html="contractor.SSQComplete | applyMarks | trustedhtml"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div ng-switch-when="false"><span style="color:red" ng-bind-html="contractor.SSQComplete | applyMarks | trustedhtml"></span></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
```

Here is the filter code in my Angular Controller:

```
 $scope.search = function (row) {
        return (angular.lowercase(row.vchCompanyName).indexOf($scope.query || '') !== -1 || angular.lowercase(row.CompanyID).indexOf($scope.query || '') !== -1 || row.CompanyType.indexOF($scope.query2 || '') !== -1);
    };
```

As someone suggested, I tried making the custom filter below:

```
app.filter('searchArrayFilter', [function () {
    return function (rows, query, query2) { // your filter take an array, and two query as parameters
        return rows.filter(function (row) {
            return (angular.lowercase(row.vchCompanyName).indexOf(query || '') !== -1 || angular.lowercase(row.CompanyID).indexOf(query || '') !== -1 || row.CompanyType.indexOf(query2 || '') !== -1);
        });
    }
}])
```

I changed by HTML to this:

```
                  <tr ng-repeat="contractor in contractors |  searchArrayFilter:query:query2 ">
```

But now, I MUST select something in the dropdown AND type something in the textbox for the filter to work.  I find this strange since I am using an '||' or operator, but it is behaving like '&&'.

ANY assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should use a custom filter. Check this for more info about: http://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/

Comment: @swordf1zh what do you think `searchArrayFilter` is? it is a custom filter

Comment: When I posted my comment you were not using custom filters..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a custom filter.  The problem that I was having after creating the filter was the in the "logic" of the filter.  After changing the '||' to '&&', the filter worked as desired.  The "final" filter is as follows:

```
app.filter('searchArrayFilter', [function () {
    return function (rows, query, query2) { // your filter take an array, and two query as parameters
        return rows.filter(function (row) {
            return ((angular.lowercase(row.vchCompanyName).indexOf(query || '') !== -1 || angular.lowercase(row.CompanyID).indexOf(query || '') !== -1) && row.CompanyType.indexOf(query2 || '') !== -1);
        });
    }
}])
```

I hope that this helps someone else.  Have a great day!